# Inorder predecessor of a BST: shortest path of communication that follows the hierarchy

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, traversal, inorder

I've taken time to check out similar questions and answers on the site and implemented some but i'm still stuck, it seems my problem is a bit different and tricky. I'm faced with a scenario where i have to determine the shortest path of communication that follows the hierarchy of a node given the node as input. Say i have a tree as such:
                                                                                CEO
                                                                                   |
                                                           -----------------------------------------
                                                          |                                                   |
                                               Director Admin                             Director Finance
                                                          |                                                   |
                                                          |                                         -------------------
                                                          |                                        |                        |
                                                   Manager 1                      Manager 2          Manager 3
                                                          |
                                               -------------------
                                              |                        |
                                     Supervisor 1          Supervisor 2

And this is my JAVA code

```
public class StaffChartTraversal {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Node<String> one = new Node<String>("1","CEO", "");
    Node<String> two = new Node<String>("2","Director Admin", "1");
    Node<String> three = new Node<String>("3","Director Finance", "1");
    Node<String> four = new Node<String>("6","Manager 1", "2");
    Node<String> five = new Node<String>("12","Manager 2", "3");
    Node<String> six = new Node<String>("15","Manger 3", "3");
    Node<String> seven = new Node<String>("16","Supervisor 1", "6");
    Node<String> eight = new Node<String>("17","Supervisor 2", "6");
    one.setLeft(two);
    one.setRight(three);
    two.setLeft(four);
    three.setLeft(five);
    three.setLeft(six);
    four.setLeft(seven);
    four.setRight(eight);
    inorder(seven);
}

private static class Node<T> {

    public Node<T> left;
    public Node<T> right;
    public T data1;
    public T data2;
    public T data3;

    public Node(T data1, T data2, T data3) {
        this.data1 = data1;
        this.data2 = data2;
        this.data3 = data3;
    }

    public Node<T> getLeft() {
        return this.left;
    }

    public void setLeft(Node<T> left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public Node<T> getRight() {
        return this.right;
    }

    public void setRight(Node<T> right) {
        this.right = right;
    }
}

public static void inorder(Node<?> n) {
    if (n != null) {
        inorder(n.getLeft());
        System.out.print(n.data2 + "(" + n.data1 + ")" + " ");
        inorder(n.getRight());
    }
}
```

}

Now when given a node as input in the `inorder()` method it should print the shortest path of communication that follows the hierarchy. So if I was to enter `seven` which represents `Supervisor 1` such as `inorder(seven)` the program should output:

```
Supervisor 1 (16) Manager 1 (6) Director Admin (2) CEO(1)
```

But from my implementation I get just this as the output:

```
Supervisor 1(16)
```

Please i need help in fixing my code... Thanks

EDIT:
I have fixed the initial issue as pointed out above thanks to @nash_ag but then I want to extend the inorder() method to accept 2 params left and right children of a parent so that if given `inorder(five, six)` it should return `Manager 2 (12) Director Finance (3) Manager 3 (15)`. Also if given `inorder(seven, six)` it should return `Supervisor 1 (16) Manager 1 (6) Director Admin (2) CEO(1) Director Finance (3) Manager 3 (15)`

My edited Java code is:

```
public class StaffChartTraversal {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Node<String> zero = null;
    Node<String> one = new Node<String>(zero, "1", "CEO", "");
    Node<String> two = new Node<String>(one, "2", "Director Admin", "1");
    Node<String> three = new Node<String>(one, "3", "Director Finance", "1");
    Node<String> four = new Node<String>(two, "6", "Manager 1", "2");
    Node<String> five = new Node<String>(three, "12", "Manager 2", "3");
    Node<String> six = new Node<String>(three, "15", "Manager 3", "3");
    Node<String> seven = new Node<String>(four, "16", "Supervisor 1", "6");
    Node<String> eight = new Node<String>(four, "17", "Supervisor 2", "6");
    one.setLeft(two);
    one.setRight(three);
    two.setLeft(four);
    three.setLeft(five);
    three.setLeft(six);
    four.setLeft(seven);
    four.setRight(eight);
    inorder(four, five);

}

private static class Node<T> {

    public Node<T> parent;
    public Node<T> left;
    public Node<T> right;
    public T data1;
    public T data2;
    public T data3;

    public Node(Node<T> parent, T data1, T data2, T data3) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.data1 = data1;
        this.data2 = data2;
        this.data3 = data3;
    }

    public Node<T> getParent() {
        return this.parent;
    }

    public Node<T> getLeft() {
        return this.left;
    }

    public void setLeft(Node<T> left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public Node<T> getRight() {
        return this.right;
    }

    public void setRight(Node<T> right) {
        this.right = right;
    }
}

public static void inorder(Node<?> n, Node<?> m) {
    if ((n != null) && (m != null)) {
        System.out.print(n.data2 + "(" + n.data1 + ") ");
        if (n.getParent().equals(m.getParent())) {
            inorder(n.getParent(), null);
        } else {
            inorder(n.getParent(), m.getParent());
        }
        System.out.print(" " +m.data2 + "(" + m.data1 + ")");
    }
}
```

}

It works well for `inorder(seven, six)` but for `inorder(five, six)` it returns `Manager 2 (12) <With no common ancestor> Manager 3 (15)` instead of `Manager 2 (12) Director Finance (3) Manager 3 (15)` Please guys help me out

Comment: Input "seven" implies to me that you are doing a depth first search which lands on "supervisor 1" as the seventh node you reach.  What is the meaning of the number in parentheses?

Comment: The 1st is the staff ID and the other is the direct manager ID

Comment: I'm suppose to use the manager ID (which is the parent ID) to connect to a child. I'm a bit confuse plz help

Answer (score 0):

Right now your code does not hold a pointer for the `parent` of each node and when you run `inorder(seven)` for the first time you get `n = seven` which runs fine, but being a leaf node (`seven` aka `Supervisor 1`) -- does not have any children, thus both the calls to `inorder(right)` and `inorder(left)` return `null`. Hence the output which you see.

For the solution either you need to keep a pointer for the parent for each `Node` if you want to traverse the tree in this way, or keep a pointer to the `root` and then use `inorder` on that.

```
private static class Node<T> {

    public Node<T> parent;
    public Node<T> left;
    public Node<T> right;
    public T data1;
    public T data2;
    public T data3;

    public Node(Node<T> parent, T data1, T data2, T data3) { 
      this.parent = parent;
    ...

    public Node<T> getParent() {
      return this.parent;
    }
```

Similarly while instantiating:

```
Node<String> six = new Node<String>(two, "15","Manger 3", "3");
Node<String> seven = new Node<String>(four, "16","Supervisor 1", "6");
Node<String> eight = new Node<String>(four, "17","Supervisor 2", "6");
```

The function now becomes much simpler:

```
public static void inorder(Node<?> n) {
  if (n != null) {
    System.out.print(n.data2 + "(" + n.data1 + ")" + " ");
    inorder(n.getParent());
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay... so what do you suggest I do? Please any form of code implementation is highly appreciated

Comment: easiest way is to go for keeping the `parent node` ref in each `Node`. I am updating with code :)

Comment: Great it worked but a little issue still it didn't follow the path as in the diagram i illustrated in my question. Instead of  `Supervisor 1 (16) Manager 1 (6) Director Admin (2) CEO(1)` its returning `Supervisor 1 (16) Manager 3 (15) Director Finance (3) CEO(1)`

Comment: Ahh, thats because I took the wrong parent in the example illustrated. (Corrected above). Essentially you can correct parent for all the nodes according to the graph you provided :)

Comment: I want to extend the inorder() method to accept 2 params left and right children of a parent so that if given `inorder(five, six)` it should return `Manager 2 (12) Director Finance (3) Manager 3 (15)`. Also if given `inorder(seven, six)` it should return `Supervisor 1 (16) Manager 1 (6) Director Admin (2) CEO(1) Director Finance (3) Manager 3 (15)` Is this possible?

Comment: Yes you might want to google "Lowest Common Ancestor", mainly using set for both nodes parent (recursive) and whenever there is an intersection in the `Sets` just print both of them and return.

Comment: Okay... Thanks let me sit on that now. Please will get back to you if I encounter any difficulties again

Comment: Still having some issues, take a look at what I've done. I update the code

Answer (score 0):

I came across these tutorials [LOWEST COMMON ANCESTOR IN A BINARY TREE](http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/lowest-common-ancestor-in-a-binary-tree-not-binary-search-tree/) and [PRINT A PATH FROM ROOT TO NODE IN BINARY TREE](http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/print-a-path-from-root-to-node-in-binary-tree/) they aided me in resolving the issue lastly. I first got the LCA of the two nodes i'm check the use the LCA to create the shortest path of communication code. See methods below:

```
//get and stores path of first child node to root
public Boolean getNodePath1(Node root, Node dest) {
    //checks return false if root is empty
    if (root == null) {
        return false;
    }
    //Checks if root is the same as destination child node before printing on both left and right
    if (root == dest || getNodePath1(root.left, dest) || getNodePath1(root.right, dest)) {
        //adds the obtained path to an ArrayList
        path1.add(root.empName + " (" + root.empID + ")");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//get and stores path of second child node to root
public Boolean getNodePath2(Node root, Node dest) {
    //checks return false if root is empty
    if (root == null) {
        return false;
    }
    //Checks if root is the same as destination child node before printing on both left and right applying recursion
    if (root == dest || getNodePath2(root.left, dest) || getNodePath2(root.right, dest)) {
        path2.add(root.empName + " (" + root.empID + ")");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//get the Lowest Common Ancestor of two nodes
public Node getLCA(Node root, Node n1, Node n2) {
    //checks return false if root is empty
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        //compares if a child node entered is the LCA
        if (root.empName.equals(n1.empName) || root.empName.equals(n2.empName)) {
            return root;
        }
        //applying recursion on both left and right nodes to derive LCA
        Node left = getLCA(root.left, n1, n2);
        Node right = getLCA(root.right, n1, n2);

        if (left != null && right != null) {
            return root;
        }
        if (left != null) {
            return left;
        } else if (right != null) {
            return right;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

//displays the formatted output of the shortest path of communication between the nodes that follows the hierarchy
public void showResult(OrgChartTraversal i, Node root, Node x, Node y) {
    Node z = i.getLCA(root, x, y);  //assign the LCA as the root
    //initialize new ArrayList to handle nodes
    path1 = new ArrayList();
    path2 = new ArrayList();
    //get both children nodes path to root
    i.getNodePath1(z, x);
    i.getNodePath2(z, y);
    //get the last elements which is the root for the both ArrayList which holds the derived children nodes paths
    Object str1 = path1.get(path1.size() - 1);
    Object str2 = path2.get(path2.size() - 1);
    if (str1.equals(str2)) {
        path1.remove(str1);     //remove the root in first child node path so it doesn't make the output cumbersome
        path2.remove(str2);     //remove the root in second child node path so it doesn't make the output cumbersome
    }
    //reverse the order of second child node path so it matches the requirement in the output
    Collections.reverse(path2);
    //iterate through the nodes that forms the path and print it out
    it1 = path1.iterator();
    it2 = path2.iterator();
    while (it1.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(it1.next() + " -> ");
    }
    System.out.print(z.empName + " (" + z.empID + ")");
    while (it2.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(" <- " + it2.next());
    }
}
```